# Android Development Tools full of bugs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

A few days ago my Eclipse (3.7.2) updated ADT (20.0.0). After that developing GUI became a real pain, however some of the issues below have been there before..

That's the list of issues that occur regularly, but not every time:

1. When I scroll the properties window i suddenly scrolls back. No matter how many times I retry it won't stop. Using mouse wheel or scrollbar gives the same result. It always scrolls back to the same position (like there was a certain property cached somewhere)
2. When I open the layout as xml and hover over a line of text it disappears and appears a few lines above, below.
3. When I open a design xml in designer it won't generate a preview. After I close this file and open it again (sometimes multiple times) it usually appears in the end. (no errors in xml)
4. On top of the designer window where are a few icons (Set Orientation, Change Margind, etc.) they tend to blink like disco..

This one appears all the time:

1. (only in designer) For Height and Width I only can set fill_parent or wrap_content values. It's impossible to set a numeric value like 0dip.

Do you have the same problems? Can any of them be fixed?

PS I'm using Widows 7

Comment: I feel your pain but I think this belongs to the official ADT / plugin issue tracker. A lot of stuff is seriously screwed up right now with the latest version of ADT and I doubt that (from our user point of view) there are simple fixes available other than clearing lint markers, cleaning projects and workspaces :-(

Comment: @gisek I am having same problem ,Have you fixed it?

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj I gave up developping Android apps. I switched to .Net about a yeat ago, so I won't be much help anymore :(